# Move all elements of an array to the right

Tags: java, arrays

So ive got an array of size 22, that reads in a number from the console and adds the number to the array. so if 123456 is read in the array will print out

12345600000000... something along those lines.

I need to right justify this number to perform arithmetic operations, but i cant seem to get the loop structure right to output the number!

```
int[] newlong = new int[22];
String inputline = "";

public void readNewLong()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    inputline = in.nextLine();

    try
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < inputline.length(); i ++)
         {
              char a = inputline.charAt(i);
              String b = "" + a;
              newlong[i] = Integer.parseInt(b);
         }

    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException, you must enter a string of digits. " + nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is what reads in the number, inputline and store it in the array newLong.

The method below is what is not working...

```
public void rightJustify()
{
     printLong();
     System.out.println(inputline.length());

     for(int i = 0; i< inputline.length(); i++)
     {
         for(int j = 0; j < newlong.length; j++)
         {
              newlong[j] = (newlong[j] - (inputline.length() -i));
         }  
     }
     printLong();      
}
```

Comment: Would this happen to be homework?

Answer (score 2):

Why you want justify to right actually you can enter in correct order?

If newlong[] is global then has 0 in all positions

```
for (int i = inputline.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    char a = inputline.charAt(i);
    String b = "" + a;
    newlong[22 - inputline.length() + i] = Integer.parseInt(b);
}
```

**edited:**
If you prefer your justify method I recommend you:

```
public void rightJustify() {
    System.out.println(inputline.length());

    for (int i = inputline.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        newlong[22 - inputline.length() + i] = newlong[i];
        newlong[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to do it with the loop structure to get a better understanding of array manipulation, but i seem to have gone wrong with my algorithm and i cant figure out why!

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't align to the right when you read your data ?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputline = in.nextLine();

    StringBuilder inputData = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputline.length(); i++) {
            char a = inputline.charAt(i);
            inputData.append(a);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length(); i++) {
            newlong[newlong.length - inputData.length() + i] = Integer
                    .parseInt("" + inputData.charAt(i));
        }

        printLong(newlong);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out
                .println("NumberFormatException, you must enter a string of digits. "
                        + nfe.getMessage());
    }
```

This an output

```
    123456
    0000000000000000123456
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange way to parse an integer. Be that as it may, you don't need a nested loop to right justify the array:

```
// len is the number of digits of input.
public void rightJustify(int[] digits, int len)
{
    int off = digits.length() - len;
    for (int i = len; i-- > 0; ) digits[i + off] = digits[j];
    for (int i = off; i-- > 0; ) digits[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's obviously homework which is why we're using for loops, but in practice I'd just use:

```
// len is the number of digits of input.
public void rightJustify(int[] digits, int len) {
    System.arraycopy(digits, 0, digits, len, digits.length() - len);
    System.fill(digits, 0, len, 0);
}
```

No reason to reinvent the wheel, even if the function is trivial enough for it imho.